# Highlight Selected Option Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight the selected value from a dropdown list, which works... but when you select another item from the list, that gets highlighted as well. It keeps on adding to other items as you select them. How do I remove it from the old `<option>` when the new `<option>` is selected? Check out my JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4Vhd/). I know I'm supposed to use an `if/else` statement, but not sure how.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick responses everyone.

Comment: If you post a good, well explained, relatively simple question, people usually answer within a couple of minutes, tops. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the class from the other elements first.

Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/CzuGF/

Line 3:

```
$('select option').removeClass('highlight');
```

Comment: Great! Works perfectly. But I'm curious why the class needs to be removed first? Why can't it go on Line 6? The way I thought it functions is as you add the class, and then you remove it.

Comment: Think about it ... if you first add your class, *then* remove all highlight classes from all options, the one you selected wouldn't show up. You have to first clear all highlight classes from all options, then set only the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t4Vhd/4/)

```
var highlighted="";
$(function () {
    $('#places').change(function () {
        //if there is a previous selection, then remove highlight class
        if(highlighted!="")
            $('select option:contains(' + highlighted+ ')').removeClass('highlight')
        //store the current selection in temp var
        highlighted=$(this).val();
        $('select option:contains(' + $(this).val() + ')').addClass('highlight')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This code work like a charm and can be reused if you have multiple `select` :

```
$(function () {
    $('select').change(function () { //Can change the selector to you input class if you want, doesnt matter
        $(this).find('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).find('option:contains(' + $(this).val() + ')').addClass('highlight');
    })
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/t4Vhd/5/

**OR**

```
$(function () {
    $('select').change(function () { //Can change the selector to you input class if you want, doesnt matter
        $(this).find('option:contains(' + $(this).val() + ')').addClass('highlight').siblings().removeClass('highlight');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your code, before you add the class.

```
$(this).find(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/t4Vhd/2/